# Trying to publish ASP.NET project, but VS can't find a particular file

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

One of the css files disappears from the publish obj/Release/Package/PackageTmp/ folder during publishing and then VS tells me it can't find the file. It's as if one portion of the project says to delete the file and the other tries to find the file. Any ideas? I hope I gave enough info. It's short, but pretty much sums up the issue to my knowledge.

csproj file. The only file I'm having an issue with is the survey.css file. It appears just twice in the csproj file.

```
<Content Include="greybox\logo.gif" />
<Content Include="greybox\next.gif" />
<Content Include="greybox\night_valley.jpg" />
<Content Include="greybox\night_valley_thumb.gif" />
<Content Include="greybox\night_valley_thumb.jpg" />
<Content Include="greybox\prev.gif" />
<Content Include="greybox\salt.jpg" />
<Content Include="greybox\salt_thumb.gif" />
<Content Include="greybox\w_close.gif" />
<Content Include="layout.css" />
<Content Include="obj\Debug\Survey.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt" />
<Content Include="obj\Debug\Survey.dll" />
<Content Include="obj\Debug\Survey.pdb" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Survey.dll" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\default.aspx" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\layout.css" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\survey.css" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\ThankYou.aspx" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Survey.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Survey.dll" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\Survey.pdb" />
<Content Include="obj\Release\_WPPLastBuildInfo.txt" />
<Content Include="survey.css" />
<Content Include="SurveyAdded.aspx" />
<Content Include="ThankYou.aspx" />
<Content Include="Web.config" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would open your CSProj file up in a text editor and see if you can find where that file is referenced. A simple text search will help. Either you will discover where it is hiding inside your project, or you can just delete it using the text editor.

Comment: Thanks, that helped push me in the right direction. I've updated my original post with a code snippet from the csproj file. I'm having issues with just the survey.css file. Do I need to delete something or add something? Sorry, I'm not familiar with how csproj files are set up.

Comment: <Content Include="obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\survey.css" />
delete this line and check it.

Comment: Awesome! That worked for the error, but now I have another one. Same situation, different file. I take it I should do the same thing with any other files that have this issue?

Comment: Hmm... I did that with the other file causing an issue (ThankYou.aspx) and now I'm getting an error saying it can't find Survey.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache. Is there any way to just generate a brand new csproj file? I'm beginning to think this one is all screwed up for some odd reason.

Comment: renamed assembly and rebuild solutions.

Comment: I deleted every file that was causing an error and now it's published. Don't have any way to test it just yet because it links up with another project that I don't have right now, but the files all sure look right to me. Thanks a lot!!!!